# ArcGIS import credentials with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to clear credentials to a WMS connection in Arc. According to the Arc help files, I must import said credentials so I can direct the code on what to clear. I cannot narrow down where to find the path for `ImportCredentials` method in the below snippet:

```
secured_credentials = arcpy.ImportCredentials([r"C:\Project\SecuredServices.ags"]) 

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Project\USA.aprx")

m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
```

Was this path housed somewhere when I fist connected to the server in Arc?

Comment: The `.ags` is made from within the app (ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap). Since you're using Pro, these files are generally created in the same folder as the project. (but you can make them anywhere). Your best bet is to just do a search in Explorer for `*.ags` and see what comes up.

Comment: Or are you saying that you've brought a service in from your **Portal** and you're trying to clear that connection. That Portal connection is not the same as `.ags` connection, which is a connection made directly to a **Server**